# create a itunes like Popover in Objective C for ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa, popover

I would like to create a popover like the iTunes one. It shoes for example when I edit your account informations. Like this:http://ipadinsight.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Account-Settings.jpg

thanks for your help

Comment: You forgot to post the code you currently have and the exact errors you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create and display a view controller modally.

To do this, you must set its property modalPresentationStyle to

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet
```

and show by calling method

```
–presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

on its father or

```
– presentModalViewController:animated:
```

for iOS < 6.0

It must have grouped table view inside populated with proper options